# How to set COM object to call Python script using Excel VBA?

Tags: python, excel, vba, com

I am running windows 10 on an Azure VM with Office 365 Pro Plus.

I am trying to set up a COM object to call a Python script a la http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/calling-python-class-using-vba-with-com.html

I get the clsid with

```
pip install pywin32 -> [python shell] import pythoncom -> print(pythoncom.CreateGuid())
```

and so my Python script is very simple.

To test if it works:

```
class PythonClass1(object):
    _reg_clsid_= "{<Guid from script above here>}"
    _reg_progid_= 'PythonLib1.PythonClass1'
    _public_methods_ = ['Greeting']

    def Greeting(self):
        print("this work?")
        return "Hello World"
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    print("Registering COM server...")
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonClass1)
```

I am trying to call this from VBA in Excel:

```vb
Sub TestingButton_Click()
    Dim objPython As Object
    Set objPython = CreateObject("PythonLib1.PythonClass1")
    Debug.Print objPython.Greeting()
End Sub
```

I get a loading spinner on my cursor for about five seconds then Excel crashes and restarts with a version recovery bar on the left side just like when Excel crashes normally.

I tried debug.print-ing all over in VBA and also in the Python script. Nothing in the `win32traceutil.py`, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add `_reg_clsctx_ = pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` to the class after importing the module pythoncom. That fixed it for me.